# how to fill nan value based on another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i have to filter value column_A 1st and then Fill the nan value as team 1 for abc and team 2 for def

| Column_A | Column_B |
| --- | --- |
| abc | team 1 |
| def | team 5 |
| def | team 5 |
| def | NaN |
| abc | team 1 |
| abc | NaN |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, try this using fillna:

```
df['Column_B'] = df['Column_B'].fillna(df['Column_A'].map({'abc':'team 1', 'def' : 'team 2'}))
df
```

Output:

```
  Column_A Column_B
0      abc   team 1
1      def   team 5
2      def   team 5
3      def   team 2
4      abc   team 1
5      abc   team 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set index to your reference column and use a dictionary:

```
df['Column_B'] = df.set_index('Column_A')['Column_B']\
.fillna({'abc':'team 1', 'def' : 'team 2'}).values
```